# Is there any way to get where condition from the collection?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order, sql

I want to get the `where` condition from a collection.I'm using it in my sales order grid.

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
echo $this->getCollection()->getSelect();
```

When i apply `getselect` to the collection i could see the corresponding query with where condition:

```
 SELECT `main_table`.*, `myorder`.`customer_email` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
     LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `myorder` ON myorder.entity_id = main_table.entity_id 
     WHERE (`main_table`.`status` = 'received') 
     ORDER BY main_table.created_at DESC LIMIT 20
```

But I want to know is there any other way to get `where` condition directly from the collection itself.

I want to apply that `where` to another query of mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `select` part in this way:

```
$where = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
```

There is also a `setPart()` method that can be used to set `where` condition.

---

Other possible parts from `Zend_Db_Select` are:

```
/**
 * The initial values for the $_parts array.
 * NOTE: It is important for the 'FOR_UPDATE' part to be last to ensure
 * meximum compatibility with database adapters.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected static $_partsInit = array(
    self::DISTINCT     => false,
    self::COLUMNS      => array(),
    self::UNION        => array(),
    self::FROM         => array(),
    self::WHERE        => array(),
    self::GROUP        => array(),
    self::HAVING       => array(),
    self::ORDER        => array(),
    self::LIMIT_COUNT  => null,
    self::LIMIT_OFFSET => null,
    self::FOR_UPDATE   => false
);
```